# How to edit the notification text that beside the icon?

Tags: android

How can I change the text that beside the notification icon or even can delete it?

[image]

Comment: Please first read, Notification anatomy.  setContentTitle(). https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Templates

Answer (score 0):

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(CurrentContext, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Enter title here")
    .setContentText("Optionally enter body text here");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

To update this notification after you've issued it, call `NotificationManagerCompat.notify()` again, passing it a notification with the same ID you used previously. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.

```
  Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle("Me")
    .setConversationTitle("Team lunch")
    .addMessage("Hi", timestamp1, null) // Pass in null for user.
    .addMessage("What's up?", timestamp2, "Coworker")
    .addMessage("Not much", timestamp3, null)
    .addMessage("How about lunch?", timestamp4, "Coworker"))
    .build();
```

check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Updating) for more info...